When vs while vs as

I was cooking while she screamed

Example number 1 shows that these two actions were happening at the same time. To make it more clear we could write (I was cooking while she was screaming).

I was cooking when she screamed

Example number 2 shows that "screaming" happened only for a while. It let's say interrupted my "cooking"

I was cooking as she screamed

What about 3? Is it the same as 1 or 2?

You should also add: … screamed and writhed on the kitchen linoleum in exquisite agony .

What? Hahahhaha

(1)  and (3) are highly unlikely sentences. In what situation would 'you' calmly carry on cooking while a woman was constantly screaming within earshot?

@KateBunting  I know but I want to understand how "as" works the same way as "when" or"while" if used with a simple tense. Please answer if my example number 3 is the same as 1 or 2.

Sentences like (1) and (3) are used when two ongoing activities are taking place at the same time. Scream is a very odd choice for the second verb because it's unlikely that one person would refer in such a matter-of-fact way to carrying on an activity while someone else was continuing to scream. A more natural example would be

I was cooking while she was cleaning the house.

(2) suggests that the cooking was interrupted by a single scream.

It would be also fine to say "I was cooking while she cleaned the house", right?

Certainly it would.

Thank you very much
